# Why does search condition fail on MS Access number field that is indexed?

Tags: ms-access, indexing, integer, comparison

Create a table in Access with a field that is a long int. Set the field to be indexed (either type). Create one record with value of 1. Then create a query looking for all records in that table with value less than 5. Works. Now search for records with value less than 5.5. Fails.

Should this be reported to Microsoft? I can't find a way around this, other than removing the index.

Comment: Does `< CInt(5.5)` give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the index. It expects an integer while 5.5 on its own seems to be casted to a Decimal.

So, when setting the filter, first convert using any function that always will return an integer:

Int, Fix, CInt, CLng, CByte, even CBool